# Parametric equations derivative's with $0$ in the denominator

Tags: calculus, parametric

Let's consider the following question

Let $x=\frac{t}{1+t^2},$ $y=3t^2-6t$. Find $\frac{dy}{dx}\Big|_{t=1}$.

It is known that $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dx/dt}{dy/dt}.$$

The problem is that both  $\frac{dy}{dt}\Big|_{t=1}=0$, and $\frac{dy}{dt}\Big|_{t=1}=0$. In this case, we can show that

\begin{equation}\label{a}
\frac{dy}{dx}\bigg|_{t=1}=\lim_{t\to1}\frac{dy}{dx}.
\end{equation}
My question: If $\lim_{t\to1}\frac{dy}{dx}$ exists, is it necessarily true that  $\frac{dy}{dx}\Big|_{t=1}=\lim_{t\to1}\frac{dy}{dx}$. ?

Thanks

Comment: I can't understand what exactly you're working over with ? Also your question is a little bit weirdly stated. You say 0 in the *denominator*, where is the denominator you are referring too

Comment: @Rebellos The derivative $dy/dx=\frac{dy/dt}{dx/dt}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f$ be a continuous function at $a$, and let it be differentiable on some punctured neighbourhood of $a$, with $\lim_{x\to a}f'(x)$ defined.

Given [L'Hôpital's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule), we have that:

$f'(a):=\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}=\lim_{x\to a} f'(x)$

In case we are talking about a curve and not of a function, the same way of thinking can be applied to components to obtain the desired result

Comment: but you are assuming that $f$ is already differentiable

Comment: In a punctured neighbourhood of $a$, yes: that is to say that $\frac{dy}{dx}$ exists finite in some (possibly punctured neighbourhood) of $a$, and this is necessary to give some meaning to $\lim_{t \to 1}\frac{dy}{dx}$